# Fizzbuzz using boolean 'not' x operator

Tags: python, boolean, fizzbuzz

Help understanding this python code would be appreciated, I'm new to coding/python:

```
for I in range (1,16):print ( not i%3) * 'FIZZ' + ( not i%5) * 'BUZZ' or i
```

When I run this code:

```
for i in range (1,16):
  print i,
  print i%3,
  print i%5,
  print (not i%3),
  print (not i % 5),
  print ( not i%3) * 'FIZZ' + ( not i%5) * 'BUZZ' or i
```

I've added some to try and understand the result,

I get:

```
1 1 1 False False 1
2 2 2 False False 2
3 0 3 True False FIZZ
4 1 4 False False 4
5 2 0 False True BUZZ
6 0 1 True False FIZZ
7 1 2 False False 7
8 2 3 False False 8
9 0 4 True False FIZZ
10 1 0 False True BUZZ
11 2 1 False False 11
12 0 2 True False FIZZ
13 1 3 False False 13
14 2 4 False False 14
15 0 0 True True FIZZBUZZ
```

As an example, not sure why `True`, returns `FIZZ/BUZZ`, when `(not i%3)` returns `0`? I thought it should return `False`, it seems the wrong way round.

Comment: `not 0` is the same is `True` because `0` is equivalent to `False`

Answer (score 0):

In the last row, `i=15`. `15%3=0` and `15%5=0`, so `not 15%3`=1 and `not 15%5`=1. 1 is equivalent to `True`, and this is why `True` is printed.

Comment: Dear Miriam, thank you for the explanation, much appreciated. Alastair